# A word that means "one who gives up easily"

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests

Xin chào! I'm new here to this forum. I have a question.

What word could be used to describe people who give up easily? And what is the antonym (opposite word) of that word?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you really talking about giving up _people_?  Casual friends, about whom you don't really care?

Comment: You want "people who are easy to give up"?  Or "people who give up easily"?  How about giving an example ... "We already had two others with the same skills as Tom, so it was easy to give him up when I chose the debate team."

Comment: Please post a sample sentence of how you would use the word with an X or ________ where the word would got.  Also, if you're just learning English, you might want to check out the [English Language Learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) site instead.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably the most common word to describe someone who gives up easily is ***quitter***:

> ***[quitter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/quitter)***
>
> NOUN
>
> _informal _
>   *[usually with negative]*  A person who gives up easily or does not have the courage or determination to finish a task.
>   *‘he's no quitter’*

There are other words that have a similar meaning, but without more context, it would be hard to recommend any of them.

For an antonym, one might say someone is ***dogged*** or ***tenacious***.  If you really want a noun, you might use ***go-getter***:

> ***[go-getter](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/go-getter)***
>
> NOUN
>
> *informal*
>   An aggressively enterprising person.
>   *‘boys are expected to be assertive go-getters’*

or ***overacheiver*** (as in, one who overachieves)

> ***[overachieve](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/overachieve)***
>
> VERB
>
> [NO OBJECT]
>    1.  Do better than is expected, especially in schoolwork.
>       *‘David continued to overachieve all through high school’*
>
> 1.1  (often as adjective **overachieving**) Be excessively dedicated to achieving success in one's work.
>       *‘overachieving geeks’*